# Publicar Solución en Capas a AZURE

Tags: c#

Resulta que tengo una solución con 3 proyectos.
Model, BussinessLogic, Presentación.

La capa de presentación es un sitio asp.net

Las otras dos capas son bibliotecas de clases referenciadas para trabajar el contenido que presentó en la capa Presentación.
Localmente funciona correctamente, la capa modelo está utilizando Entity framework.

Cambie los connections strings por los de la base de datos de azure y funciona coreectamente localmente.

Cuando realize el deploy solamente el site y Las bibliotecas de clases no las sube.

Comment: no puede no subirlas, las dll de las otras capas entiendo estan referenciadas desde el proyecto asp.net por lo tanto cuando compilas se copian al \bin, si es asi se publican directo al web app de azure. Con que tool realizaste el deploy a Azure?

Comment: Correcto las dll de model y BussinessLogic están en la carpeta bien pero el resto de documentos no. Y correcto el deploy de azure

Comment: Acaba de entender lo que me decías no hacen falta las carpetas de los proyectos por q se contienen en los .DLLs probé en el iis local en una VM y funcionó. Lo que no entiendo es por qué en Azure no funciona

Comment: Ya lo solucione me faltaba cambiar el connection string de la capa Modelo muchas gracias